# Subspaces being homeomorphic implies complements being homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $X$ and $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic, is it true that $X \setminus U$ and $X \setminus V$ are homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Not in general. $\{0,3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are homeomorphic subspaces of $[0,3]$, but $\{0,3\}\setminus\{0,3\}$ is connected, while $[0,3]\setminus\{1,2\}$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$, $U=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$, and $V=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$. Then $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic, but $X\setminus U$ is not homeomorphic to $X\setminus V$: in the latter, in each of the connected components one can remove a single point and obtain four connected components in the result, but this is not possible in the former.

But what you want to prove does not require such a strong (yet false) claim. There is a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{R}^4$ that sends $\{(0,0,x,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ to $\{(x,y,x,y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, and hence complements to complements. Being a linear map, it is continuous; being a linear automorphism, it has a continuous inverse.